# All possible array combinations for an unknown 2D array using perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to generate all the possible combinations for a 2D array generated using an user input file. I need to use perl to obtain this.
For e.g. :

Say the 2D array formed from the input file is like this -

```
[a, b, c]
[d, e]
[f, g]
```

The expected output for this input is as below -

```
 [a, d, f] 
 [a, d, g] 
 [a, e, f] 
 [a, e, g] 
 [b, d, f] 
 [b, d, g] 
 [b, e, f] 
 [b, e, g]
 [c, d, f] 
 [c, d, g] 
 [c, e, f] 
 [c, e, g]
```

Since its an user input file the number of rows and columns can be anything and hence i am unable to use fixed number of loops to create this combination.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a HW help site. If you have a bug, publish the relevant code and the error message.

Comment: You need to show the code you are having problems with, and describe the symptoms.

Comment: @Borodin: but s/he doesn't know how to write the code given a variable number of inputs.

Comment: It isn't a part of HW, needed it as a part of another code and i thought could use the expertise of ppl here at stack overflow as i am still a beginner in perl.

Answer (score 1):

You want [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product),

Using CPAN module,

```
use Set::CrossProduct;

my @arr = (
  [qw(a b c)],
  [qw(d e)],
  [qw(f g)],
);
my $iterator = Set::CrossProduct->new(\@arr);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $iterator->combinations;
```

or

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = (
  [qw(a b c)],
  [qw(d e)],
  [qw(f g)],
);

local $" = ", ";
for my $aref ( getCartesian(@arr) ) {
  print "[@$aref]\n";
}

sub getCartesian {
#
  my @input = @_;
  my @ret = map [$_], @{ shift @input };

  for my $a2 (@input) {
    @ret = map {
      my $v = $_;
      map [@$v, $_], @$a2;
    }
    @ret;
  }
  return @ret;
}
```

output

```
[a, d, f]
[a, d, g]
[a, e, f]
[a, e, g]
[b, d, f]
[b, d, g]
[b, e, f]
[b, e, g]
[c, d, f]
[c, d, g]
[c, e, f]
[c, e, g]
```

Comment: I am sure he is going to get an A+ for his HW now :]

Comment: @nrathaus perhaps if teacher doesn't ask for explanations? :)

Comment: Actually my University teacher used Google to find if someone copied, since the StackOverflow is quite high ranked ... hint hint ..

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;

my @arr = ( [qw(a b c)], [qw(d e)], [qw(f g)] );

print "[$_]\n" for map s/-/, /gr, glob
    join '-', map { '{' . ( join ',', @$_ ) . '}' } @arr;
```

Output:

```
[a, d, f]
[a, d, g]
[a, e, f]
[a, e, g]
[b, d, f]
[b, d, g]
[b, e, f]
[b, e, g]
[c, d, f]
[c, d, g]
[c, e, f]
[c, e, g]
```

Comment: Interesting use of `glob` but it has problems when element length is more than one char.

Comment: @mpapec - Good catch--thank you.  Fixed.  `glob` does well with this task.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to look at it.  If you already had the results for some number arrays and needed to add those for an additional one, you'd do something like this:

```
sub get_combinations {
    my ($existing_results, $new_array) = @_;
    my $new_results;
    for my $existing_result (@$existing_results) { 
        for my $value (@$new_array) {
            push @$new_results, [ @$existing_result, $value ];
        }
    }
    return $new_results;
}
```

Now you can simply loop over your 2D array:

```
my $inputs = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e'],
    ['f', 'g'],
];
my $results = [ [] ];  # exactly one possible combination given no inputs
for my $input ( @$inputs ) {
    $results = get_combinations( $results, $input ); 
}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $results;
```